# Concurrent producer/consumer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to implement something analogous to the producer consumer problem in Ruby. Here is my implementation:

```
class ProducerConsumerQueue
  def initialize
    @queue = []
    @queue_lock = Mutex.new
    @queue_write_lock = Mutex.new
    @queue_lock.lock
  end

  def produce product
    @queue_write_lock.synchronized do
      @queue << product
      @queue_lock.unlock if @queue_lock.locked?
    end
  end

  def consume
    @queue_lock.lock
    @queue_write_lock.synchronized { @queue.pop }
  end
end
```

I thought this would be a good implementation because

- Consumers can create and write their products whenever
- Consumers can block in the `consume` method when there is nothing to consume.

The problem, however, is that this implementation does not work in Ruby. Apparently, you cannot lock a mutex in one thread, and then unlock it in another. Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: In case you didn’t know, Ruby includes [`Queue`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) which does essentially what you’re trying to create.

Comment: I did not know that. That simplifies my life a lot. Thanks!